# PHP - Generate XML in loop using DOM library

Tags: php, xml

I'm retrieving a set of contact records from a database query, and I then need to generate an XML response that is returned to the browser.

The PHP loop that retrieves the records looks like this:

```
foreach($contacts as $contact){

        $firstName = $record->getField('first') ;
        $lastName = $record->getField('last') ;


    $recnum++; }
```

and the XML I need to generate looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <contacts>
    <contact>
        <first_name>Penny</first_name>
        <last_name>Lancaster</last_name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <first_name>Geoff</first_name>
        <last_name>McDermott</last_name>
    </contact>
 </contacts>
```

I've been able to create a single hardcoded XML response before using:

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $doc->formatOutput = true;

 $root = $doc->createElement('error');
 $doc->appendChild($root);

 $desc = $doc->createElement('description', $error);
 $root->appendChild($desc);

 echo $doc->saveXML();
```

but I can't work out the syntax to incorporate this into a loop and generate the XML dynamically.

Comment: php and xml are close friends. see this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$contactsElement = $doc->createElement('contacts');

foreach($contacts as $contact){
    // your loop, is working? What is $record?
    $firstName = $record->getField('first') ;
    $lastName = $record->getField('last') ;
    $recnum++; // is useful for something?

    $contactElement = $doc->createElement('contact');
    $firstNameElement = $doc->createElement('first_name', $firstName);
    $lastNameElement = $doc->createElement('last_name', $lastName);

    $contactElement->appendChild($firstNameElement);
    $contactElement->appendChild($lastNameElement);
    $contactsElement->appendChild($contactElement);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```